# In-App Media playback and Link Preview

Tags: android, telegram

When a link is shared in a Chat, we need to display the link preview after sharing it. If the link contains a media from youtube/vimeo/soundcloud, we need the ability to playback the link from the app itself.

Something like this.. 
https://telegram.org/blog/search-and-media

https://telegram.org/blog/link-preview

Is it possible to get information from link?

Comment: Make your own browser and crawler... that's it. Easy? Ha... not.

Comment: we have to implement it in android application.

Comment: exactly... but you'll have to make your own browser and crawler FOR android. Check Google, you have dozens of examples.

Comment: Could you Please post some link for it?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)